# Ordering 3 tables in DataTables (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables (http://datatables.net/) plugin for jQuery. I have 3 tables with the same columns, but different data, and I want to synchronize ordering them. I.e. then I order one table, I want other tables to be ordered by the same column.

JavaScript code is following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var absTable = $('#absTable').DataTable();
    var difTable = $('#difTable').DataTable();
    var relTable = $('#relTable').DataTable();

    $('#absTable').on( 'order.dt', function () {            
        var absOrder = absTable.order();
        difTable.order( [ absOrder[0][0], absOrder[0][1] ] ).draw();
        relTable.order( [ absOrder[0][0], absOrder[0][1] ] ).draw();            
    } );
    $('#difTable').on( 'order.dt', function () {
        var difOrder = difTable.order();
        absTable.order( [ difOrder[0][0], difOrder[0][1] ] ).draw();
        relTable.order( [ difOrder[0][0], difOrder[0][1] ] ).draw();
    } );
    $('#relTable').on( 'order.dt', function () {
        var relOrder = relTable.order();
        absTable.order( [ relOrder[0][0], relOrder[0][1] ] ).draw();
        difTable.order( [ relOrder[0][0], relOrder[0][1] ] ).draw();
    } );
});
```

I works fine, except for when I call `draw()` method nothing else happens, seems like js code stop executing after first `draw()`.

Could someone please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the your code causes infinite loop, since [order()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order%28%29) method causes `order.dt` event sent to other tables, and other table handlers try to order tables again.

You need to set a flag that indicates whether ordering of other table is in progress and they should ignore `order.dt` event.

See the example below for corrected code and demonstration.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var absTable = $('#example1').DataTable({ dom: 't' });
    var difTable = $('#example2').DataTable({ dom: 't' });
    var relTable = $('#example3').DataTable({ dom: 't' });
 
    var order_in_progress = false;  
    $('#example1').on( 'order.dt', function () {            
        if(!order_in_progress){
            order_in_progress = true;
          
            var absOrder = absTable.order();
            difTable.order( [ absOrder[0][0], absOrder[0][1] ] ).draw();
            relTable.order( [ absOrder[0][0], absOrder[0][1] ] ).draw();
            
            order_in_progress = false;
        }
    } );

    $('#example2').on( 'order.dt', function () {
        if(!order_in_progress){
            order_in_progress = true;
          
            var difOrder = difTable.order();
            absTable.order( [ difOrder[0][0], difOrder[0][1] ] ).draw();
            relTable.order( [ difOrder[0][0], difOrder[0][1] ] ).draw();
            
            order_in_progress = false;
        }
    } );

    $('#example3').on( 'order.dt', function () {
        if(!order_in_progress){
            order_in_progress = true;
          
            var relOrder = relTable.order();
            absTable.order( [ relOrder[0][0], relOrder[0][1] ] ).draw();
            difTable.order( [ relOrder[0][0], relOrder[0][1] ] ).draw();

            order_in_progress = false;
        }
    } );
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example1" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Size</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Small.mp3</td><td>200</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Normal.mp3</td><td>300</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Large.mp3</td><td>400</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Smallest.mp3</td><td>100</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  
<table id="example2" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Size</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Small.mp3</td><td>200</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Normal.mp3</td><td>300</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Large.mp3</td><td>400</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Smallest.mp3</td><td>100</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="example3" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Size</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Small.mp3</td><td>200</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Normal.mp3</td><td>300</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Large.mp3</td><td>400</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Smallest.mp3</td><td>100</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  
</body>
</html>
```